# C++ Directory structure for personal application using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, directory

I started creating a small game in c++. Once i got to the 7 file mark I began looking for a way to organize them. But after looking online the results just got really confusing to me. I don't know what i should put in /lib and what i should put in /include, or what directories I don't need since I'm not making a library. And using cmake makes it worse since some guides use multiple cmake files, and some use one. This is my current directory structure.

```
/game (Main project folder)
  L All my source and header files
  L CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: There is no "common" or "the best" files organization for CMake project. Take any one and write `CMakeLists.txt` appropriately.

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want to reorganize your files ? Maybe just having them all in the same directory is enough for now. Does this hinder you in any way ?

Comment: I want to organize them because i have 7 files with much more planned and i want to make them easy to find/navigate

Comment: `I want to make them easy to find/navigate` - What do you mean by "easy to find/navigate"? Do you want to search sources and headers separated? - Move sources into `src/` directory, and headers to `/include` one (directories' names could be any). Do you want to have sources and headers for one component separated from others? - Group them into per-component directories. As I said above, there is no "the best" files organization - it very depends on your needs and taste.

Comment: My suggestion would be to group them in a way that makes logical sense. eg: If in your game you have different objects which model various abstract concepts, such as `engine`, `network`, `players`, `social` etc, then I would have a directory `engine`, `network` etc